# Set formatting in RTF string?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, richtextbox, rtf

I'm using a 'Paste' button command in my view Model to copy RTF from the clipboard. `PastedText` is my string property that a RichTextBox is bound to in my view:

```
 private void FormatPastedTextCommandAction()
 {
    PastedText += Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);                   
 }
```

This works and the text is pasted on pressing the Paste button. However, I want to lock down the formatting on the paste function and remove all formatting from the pasted RTF string (colour, italics, set to black Arial 12).

I would just use `PastedText += Clipboard.GetText();`

to get the plain text but it pastes in at a different font size and I need it in RTF format. I've looked at iterating over the RTF string and doing a find/replace on font size, colour etc. but the RTF is very complex even for a couple of words.

Is there any way around this? Thanks

Comment: `GetText()` returns only the text, it doesn't include any formatting. What you see is the formatting your own code (or XAML) applied to the contents of `PastedText`.

Comment: Yes but GetText(TextDataFormat.RTF) returns RTF along with the formatting of the pasted text. I know GetText() will just return unformatted text but I need it as RTF...

Comment: Using GetText() I get the RTF formatting of the text I have typed then the plain text appended to the end of the RTF. This results in the pasted text creating a new line in the RichTextBox and FontSize of that pasted text defaulting to 16...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used code behind in the view to strip formatting from the RichTextBox itself using a 'Format' button:

```
 private void _btnFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextRange rangeOfText = new TextRange(richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentStart, richTextBoxArticleBody.Document.ContentEnd);
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, "12");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, "Arial");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, "Normal");
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, null);
        rangeOfText.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.MarginProperty, new Thickness(0));

    }
```

This does a good job and doesn't really break the MVVM pattern as the code is UI logic only.